# ¿Como leer lineas y saltarlas con open en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un programa con tkinter que hace registros de hora en un .txt con entry. El problema llega cuando escribe las dos primeras líneas. Por ejemplo:

> Línea 1: Encargo 1 ha entrado en Máquina 1 a las 14:20.
>
> Línea 2: Encargo 1 ha salido de Máquina 1 a las 17:25.

Cuando la línea 2 se escribe se supone que el encargo se ha finalizado en esa máquina, el trabajo entra en otra máquina.

Esta es la primera entrada:

```
cantidadlisto = "("+cantidad+")"
topalog = entry1.get()+" ha entrado en "+entry2.get()+" a las "+hora+" "+cantidadlisto
f = open ('Log.txt','w')
f.write(topalog)
```

Y la segunda es igual solo que cambia el texto que escribe, necesito que pueda escribir más lineas y no solo hasta la segunda. He intentado lo poco que se pero no he conseguido nada. Lo siguiente sería que escriba a continuación como

> Línea 1: Encargo 1 ha entrado en Máquina 1 a las 14:20.
>
> Línea 2: Encargo 1 ha salido de Máquina 1 a las 17:35.
>
> Línea 3: Encargo 1 ha salido de Máquina 2 a las 17:55.
>
> Línea 4: Encargo 1 ha salido de Máquina 2 a las 19:04.

Comment: `open('Log.txt', 'a')` leer la documentación siempre es importante…

Comment: Hace poco que estoy con Python, gracias. Me ha servido a medias, la primera línea la salta, pero lo escribe a continuación de la segunda y luego continúa en la tercera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias usar el comando open('Log.txt', 'a') ('a' significando anexar o adjuntar, actualmente estas 'abriendo' el archivo como 'w' lo cual truncaria todo el documento cada vez que lo 'abras'), como consejo intenta agregar '\n' al final de cada línea para evitar tener la siguiente línea unida con la última. Espero que te sirva!

Comment: @padaleiana listo, actualizada la respuesta al idioma español!